# How can I identify the system my Docker container is runninng on? Can I pass Docker daemon labels inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my Docker compose environment I want to pass the labels of the Docker daemon inside a Docker container.

I need to identify the system my Docker container is running on from inside the container. I do not want to use any parameters on my container (-e, file-mount, etc) , as this could be misconfigured easily.

(I don't want to mount /var/run/docker.sock for security reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the information of your host to you container by setting [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/). Here are some examples from the doc:

- Using the [`.env file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file):

> You can set default values for any environment variables referenced in the Compose file, or used to configure Compose, in an environment file named .env.

```yaml
services:
  web:
    env_file:
     - web-variables.env
```

- Passing environment variables to containers:

> You can pass environment variables from your shell straight through to a service’s containers with the ‘environment’ key by not giving them a value, just like with docker run -e VARIABLE ...:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    environment:
      -DEBUG
```

- Set environment variables in containers:

> You can set environment variables in a service’s containers with the ‘environment’ key, just like with docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE ...

```yaml
services:
  web:
    environment:
      -DEBUG=1
```